# Access Kedro context from decorator

Tags: python, kedro

I am trying to create a decorator in which I need some information about the project and/or catalog.  Is it possible to access the project context from inside of the decorator?  I am looking for things like project_name, catalog entry name, and pipeline node name.

I created a way to find the root directory of the by getting the functions file path `inspect.getfile(func)`, then walking up the path until I find `.kedro.yml`, but this method breaks when using a function from a library.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the context around in the nodes is not recommended and would not fit in with the Kedro architecture (see https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/06_resources/02_architecture_overview.html). The `ProjectContext` holds the a collection of nodes (i.e. pipeline), which would hold the `ProjectContext`, which then gets into dangerous recursive teritory.

Alternatives would be to either a) pass the values via parameters, and referencing them in the `node` inputs using `params:abc`, or b) passing the actual values in the decorator.

a)
For instance, `project_name` you could pass in via parameters. Either by entering it in `parameters.yml` or dynamically by overriding the method `_get_feed_dict` in the `ProjectContext` to add an entry `{"project_name": self.project_name}` to the returned dictionary.

b)
You could have a decorator that looks like this and pass it to `Node.decorate()`:

```
from functools import partial, wraps
from kedro.pipeline import Pipeline, node


def print_metadata(func, **outer_kwargs):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("METADATA: {}".format(outer_kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


p1 = Pipeline([node(...), ...])
decorated_nodes = [
    n.decorate(partial(print_metadata, node_name=n.name, catalog_entries=n.inputs))
    for n in p1.nodes
]
p2 = Pipeline(decorated_nodes)
```

Not super-pretty but can get you unstuck. What is your exact use case? Why do you need the node name and catalog entry name in the node?